# Why is APCu segfaulting inside a Docker container?

Tags: php, docker, apc

I'm trying to run PHP 5.5 (with FPM) with APCu inside a Docker container. I'm using `boot2docker` on OSX.

When I try to run `php-fpm -i`, it segfaults.

Running in `gdb`, I get the following backtrace:

```
(gdb) run -i
Starting program: /usr/local/sbin/php-fpm -i
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff542474c in __pthread_rwlock_init (rwlock=rwlock@entry=0xffffffffffffffff, attr=attr@entry=0x7ffff1bda988 <apc_lock_attr>) at pthread_rwlock_init.c:40
40  pthread_rwlock_init.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff542474c in __pthread_rwlock_init (rwlock=rwlock@entry=0xffffffffffffffff, attr=attr@entry=0x7ffff1bda988 <apc_lock_attr>) at pthread_rwlock_init.c:40
#1  0x00007ffff19ca9d0 in apc_lock_create (lock=lock@entry=0xffffffffffffffff) at /tmp/pear/temp/apcu/apc_lock.c:180
#2  0x00007ffff19d0135 in apc_sma_api_init (sma=0x7ffff1bda540 <apc_sma>, data=<optimized out>, expunge=<optimized out>, num=<optimized out>, size=<optimized out>, mask=<optimized out>) at /tmp/pear/temp/apcu/apc_sma.c:323
#3  0x00007ffff19ccac9 in zm_startup_apcu (type=0, module_number=35) at /tmp/pear/temp/apcu/php_apc.c:284
#4  0x00000000007198b6 in zend_startup_module_ex ()
#5  0x0000000000725565 in zend_hash_apply ()
#6  0x000000000071d32a in zend_startup_modules ()
#7  0x00000000006b9413 in php_module_startup ()
#8  0x00000000007d9da5 in ?? ()
#9  0x000000000042e684 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007ffff5657b45 in __libc_start_main (main=0x42de80, argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffec08, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffebf8) at libc-start.c:287
#11 0x000000000042f7fa in _start ()
(gdb)
```

I thought this might be some general problem with phtreads in a Docker container, but I haven't been able to find any reports of that kind of problem.

Some questions:

1. Is this a known issue (and, so, trying to fix this through configuration is fruitless)?
2. What is the significance of `40 pthread_rwlock_init.c: No such file or directory.`?